# If $J$ is tangent point of $GH$ with incircle of $FGH$ and $D$ is intersection of $F$-mixtilinear inclrcle with $(FGH)$, then $\angle FGH=\angle GDJ$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

Let $FGH$ be a triangle with circumcircle $A$ and incircle $B$, the latter with touchpoint $J$ in side $GH$. Let $C$ be a circle tangent to sides $FG$ and $FH$ and to $A$, and let $D$ be the point where $C$ and $A$ touch, as shown here.

[image]

Prove that $\angle FGH = \angle GDJ$.

Comment: Adding opposite angles of the cyclic quadrilateral $GFHD$ and also all of the triangles to get $\pi$, but that got me nowhere.

Comment: Can you give a description of how the figure is constructed? I mean which point is center of circle and so on..

Comment: @Aniket - Good question, but sorry. The figure, and the one line is all there is to it.

Comment: It seems to me that the construction is as follows: draw a circle A.  Choose three arbitrary points on the perimeter and inscribe a triangle FGH. Within the triangle, inscribe a circle B.  J is the point at which the circle and FGH intersect on segment GH.  Inscribe a circle C tangent to segments FG, FH and circle A.  Point D is the point at which circles A and C intersect.  Prove that angle FGH equals angle GDJ.

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt - Saw it on CasualMath@Reddit. It's a day old now, and so far no one has solved it.

Comment: also posted later (by another user) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549838/geometry-puzzle-show-that-x-y)

Comment: Indeed, I posted it both on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CasualMath/comments/3ucv19/geometry_puzzle_prove_that_xy/) and here.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this thread?  It has a complete description of the problem, whilst the one posted later doesn't.

Comment: Let $F^\prime$ be the reflection of $F$ in the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{GH}$. Define $D$ to be the (other) point at which $\overleftrightarrow{F^\prime J}$ meets the circumcircle. By construction, one readily shows that $D$ is such that $x = y$ as in the figure; moreover, this construction allows for a straightforward (though very tedious) coordinate proof that $D$ is indeed the point of tangency of the circumcircle and the green circle.

Comment: It's easy to prove if you make $FGH$ a regular triangle

Comment: I.e. equilateral?

Comment: @Fibonacci Yes, equilateral. $F$, $D$, $J$ and the centers of the circles are all in one line then, so you can use the formulas for the circumradius and the height of a regular triangle ($R = \frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $h = \frac{a\sqrt{3}}{2}$) to get JD, from which you can calculate that $\angle{GDJ} = 60^{\circ}$. But it's only a proof for that specific case, not sure how to move on from there..

Comment: I'm not sure that helps, most results are trivial with an equilateral triangle. Even easier, you could argue from symmetry that $\angle GDJ=\angle JDH$ and thus equal to $\frac\pi 3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

**Notations:**

Write $a:=GH$, $b:=HF$, $c:=FG$, and $s:=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$.  Let $\Omega$ and $\omega$ be the circumcircle and the incircle of $FGH$, respectively.  The circle internally tangent to $FG$, $FH$, and $\Omega$ is denoted by $\Gamma$.  Suppose that $\Gamma$ intersects $HF$ and $FG$ at $P$ and $Q$, respectively.  Denote by $\omega_a$ the excircle opposite to $F$ of $FGH$, which touches $GH$ at $T$.  Extend $FT$ to meet $\Omega$ again at $S$. Finally, $\theta:=\angle GFD$.

---

**Proof:**

Let $i$ be the inversion at $F$ with radius $FP=FQ$.  Then, $i(\Gamma)=\Gamma$, whereas $i(\Omega)$ is the tangent to $\Gamma$ at the point $E$, where $E$ is the second intersection between $\Gamma$ and $FD$.  Suppose that $i(\Omega)$ meets $HF$ at $G'$ and $FG$ at $H'$.  As $FG'H'$ and $FGH$ are similar triangles and $\Gamma$ is the excircle opposite to $F$ of $FG'H'$, it follows that $$\angle HFS=\angle HFT=\angle H'FE=\angle GFD=\theta\,.$$

Consequently, the minor arcs $HS$ and $GD$ of the circle $\Omega$ subtend the same angle $\theta$ at the circumference, so they are equal.  Ergo, $HS=GD$.  Since $TH=s-b=JG$ and $$\angle THS=\angle GHS=\angle GFS=\angle HFD=\angle HGD=\angle JGD\,,$$ we conclude that $GDJ$ and $HST$ are congruent triangles.  Thence, $$\angle GDJ=\angle HST=\angle HSF=\angle FGH\,.$$

---

**P.S.:**

It can be shown, using Casey's Theorem, that the center of $\omega$ is the midpoint of $PQ$.  Also, one can see that the internal angular bisector of $\angle FGH$ meets the line $DP$ at a point on $\Omega$, at which the tangent line $\ell_b$ is parallel to $HF$.  Likewise, the internal angular bisector of $\angle GHF$ meets the line $DQ$ at a point on $\Omega$, at which the tangent line $\ell_c$ is parallel to $FG$.  Finally, if $Z$ is the point of intersection between $\ell_b$ and $\ell_c$, then $Z$, $F$, $D$ are collinear.

Answer (score 5):

This is NOT an answer but is an as-accurate-as-possible re-sketch of the original figure after guessing. Please let me know if there is any mis-interpretation.

[Note: The previous diagrams have been incorrectly drawn and were therefore deleted. The one below is the most updated version. Sorry for giving some misleading info.]

[image]

This time Geogebra shows that the two mentioned angles are actually **equal**.

PS: Maybe the OP can disclose the source of the question.

Comment: +1 for geogebra. Can you move B, C and D around on the circle to produce more dramatic counterexamples? What if BD is a diagonal, so C is a right angle?

Comment: @Mick: I think you may have made an error in construction.  The angles are indeed equal.

Comment: @EthanBolker (and also to Mirko) B, C, D were drawn to be movable. As can be seen from my second upload, if BC = BD (i.e. GF = GH in the original), the situation is even worst.

Comment: What is the role of the point labeled $G$ on your picture? Presumably the center of the green circle, but it is not (as the "radius" above it is shorter than the "radius" below it, on the first picture). It makes me think @Edward might be right, I no longer follow what this picture is trying to show. Or, do you have a way to construct the green circle without constructing its center?

Comment: the pictures I made show the angles are the same (but are not good enough for a proof). The pictures shown in this answer are imprecise, the center of the green circle is not $G$, the touching point of the big circle and the green circle is not drawn correctly. @EthanBolker

Comment: @EthanBolker Pls see the updated version.

Comment: @Edward You are right. Corrected.

Comment: @Mirko I have seen your upload. This time, I draw the black circle first and then followed by the green circle such that they touch each other internally. Finally, I draw the red circle. Now, I find that the mentioned angles are equal.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Evan Chen's mixtilinear incircle article in [here](http://www.mit.edu/~evanchen/handouts/Mixt-GeoGuessr/Mixt-GeoGuessr.pdf), the results become trivial.

I will change some notations.

In $\triangle ABC$, let the incircle hit $BC$ at $D$ and the $A$-mixtilinear incircle hit the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $E$. Prove that $\angle DEB = \angle ABC$.

Since (9) holds, we have $\angle DTM_A = \angle AFB=180-\angle B - \frac{1}{2}\angle A$, where $F = AI \cap BC$.

Since $\angle BTM_A = 180-\frac{1}{2} \angle A$, we have $$\angle DTB = \angle BTM_A - \angle DTM_A = \angle B = \angle ABC$$ as desired.

Answer (score 2):

The pictures I made with Cinderella Geometry show that the problem is stated correctly. The answer is that indeed $x=y$. (Of course, a proof is needed.)

[image: angles are indeed equal]

A different triangle, angles again are equal.

[image: angles again equal]

Answer (score 1):

Here's part of a solution based on a comment from @Blue.

Here's the picture showing a few additional points and lines. 
[image: Geometric puzzle]

### Angle equivalence

As per the suggestion from @Blue, we first reflect the point $F$ about the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{GH}$.  Then we draw a segment $\overline{F'D}$.  Since $\overline{F'G} = \overline{FH}$, the law of sines says that $\sin{\angle{x}} = \sin{\angle{y}}$.  Since both are interior angles of a triangle, $x < \pi, y < \pi$, so either $y = x$ or $y = \pi -x$.

Next, we note that by the law of sines, $\sin(\angle{GFH})=\sin(\angle{HDG})$. Since neither angle can be greater than $\pi$, either $\angle{GFH}=\angle{HDG}$ or $\angle{GFH}=\pi-\angle{HDG}$.

If one could prove that $F'$ and $J$ and $D$ are collinear, that would be the end of the proof, but it is not yet obvious to me how one would do that.

Comment: Since $GFHD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, opposite angles add up to $\pi$, that is, $\angle GFH+\angle HDG=\pi$, and thus $\angle FGH+\angle GHF=\angle HDG$. Don't know if that helps a bit.