# Geometry puzzle - Show that $x = y$

Tags: geometry, puzzle

**Problem**

In the following figure, show that $x = y$.

[image]

**My attempts**

Sadly nothing of value. I have far too little experience with geometry to even begin trying to solve this.

Comment: exact duplicate [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547510/prove-that-angle-fgh-angle-gdj) asked a day before this

Comment: The [original post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547510/prove-that-angle-fgh-angle-gdj) is getting close-votes, despite both being the ostensible source *and* having a complete description. I'd prefer to close this one as a duplicate, but since only this question has received responses (though no complete answers), this doesn't seem possible. Hmmmm ...